# New Windows Server 2008 R2 WIMP running slower than Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, php5, mysql5.5

We recently upgraded a WIMP server from Windows Server 2003 (32 bit) to Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit).

The new server has significantly better hardware than the old server, yet many processes take much longer than the old box. We have a rather complex web application process that normally takes about 7 seconds on the old box, but on the new one it takes 11-12 seconds.  That's down from 15.5 seconds it took before I disabled IPv6.

This process involves some queries (some of them involve transactions with maybe 3 queries between the start and commit) and creating and emailing some PDFs.

Windows updates are current with a more or less fresh machine.  This happens consistently even when we have almost no traffic on the site. Memory and CPU aren't being hard pressed at all.

The only differences between the servers other than the OS and hardware:

1. When available, we used 64 bit versions of programs.
2. The new server uses MySQL 5.5 rather than MySQL 5.1 (I did run the mysql_upgrade program and we use InnoDB for the engine)
3. The new server uses PHP Version 5.3.18 rather than PHP Version 5.3.1
4. With the new OS came IIS7 rather than IIS6 of course.

What could be causing better hardware to run so much slower?

Comment: What is the disk layout on the old and be servers?

Comment: There are two drives on both servers, new one has larger drives, but there's no raid or anything as far as I am aware. (Godaddy host)

Comment: Rotation speed? SATA vs SAS? Controller cache? etc etc? These things matter and could very well explain your problem.

Comment: Old server:
ST3120813AS
ST3320620AS
New server:
both drives ST1000DM003-9YN162

They are all SATA drives and have 7200 rpm